# Scala string interpolation: Escape double quote

Tags: scala, string-interpolation

I am trying to use the confluent registry and am running into issues regarding schema formatting.

I have a schema:

```
val mySchema = "{ \"type\": \"string\" }"
```

The schema registry expects the schema to be formatted like this:

```
{"schema" : "{ \"type\": \"string\" }" }
```

On trying this:

```
    val formatted =  s"""{"schema": "$mySchema"}"""
    //formatted: String = "{\"schema\": \"{\"type\" : \"string\"}\"}"
```

which is not what I need (note the `\"schema\"`, and the `\"` literal pre/suffixed to the schema value)

Appreciate comments/inputs.

Comment: `raw"""\foo"""` doesn't do interpretation of backslash. Is that the question?

Comment: Your `formatted` line should work if you can change `mySchema` to `"""{ \"type\": \"string\" }"""`

Comment: Yes, it does work when I format `mySchema` like you said and format `formatted` to a multi-line `s"""{
"schema": "$mySchema" 
}"""`
Single line does not work though, strangely.

Answer (score 0):

Does following satisfies your requirements

```
    object Main extends App {
      def formatSchema(schema: String) = schema.replace("\"", "\\\"")

      val mySchema  = "{ \"type\": \"string\" }"
      val formatted = s"""{"schema": "${formatSchema(mySchema)}"""

      println(formatted)
    }


    ========= Output ==========
    {"schema": "{ \"type\": \"string\" }
```